# Find cell location if blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Sud that tells me if a column has a blank cell.

Is there a way to also get the cell location if it is blank, There can be thousands of row and maybe one or two blank cells, they are easy to miss even if you know it is there.

Thanks

```
Sub CountBlankCellsComments()

Dim Lastrow As Long

Sheets("Comments").Select
With Sheets("Comments")
Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("A2:E" & Lastrow)) = 0 Then

            MsgBox "There Are (0) Blank Cells For ""Comments"" Sheet"
        Else

MsgBox "For Comments Sheet There are:" & vbCrLf & vbLf & _
"(" & WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("A2:A" & Lastrow)) & ") Blank Cells in Column A" & vbCrLf & vbLf & _
"(" & WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("B2:B" & Lastrow)) & ") Blank Cells in Column B" & vbCrLf & vbLf & _
"(" & WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("C2:C" & Lastrow)) & ") Blank Cells in Column C" & vbCrLf & vbLf & _
"(" & WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("D2:D" & Lastrow)) & ") Blank Cells in Column D" & vbCrLf & vbLf & _
"(" & WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("E2:E" & Lastrow)) & ") Blank Cells in Column E"

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim blanks As Range

With Worksheets("Comments")
  On Error Resume Next
  Set blanks = Application.Intersect(.Range("A2", .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)), .Range("A:E")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  On Error GoTo 0
End With

If blanks Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "There Are (0) Blank Cells For ""Comments"" Sheet"
Else

  blanks.Select

  MsgBox "For Comments Sheet There are (" & blanks.Cells.Count & ") Blank Cells:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    blanks.Address

End If
```

Comment: Hello GSerg, when I run your Sub I get only the first empty cell it encounters, I made two empty cell to test with is the sub suppose to capture all the empty cells or just the first?.  Thanks

Comment: @Tim No, it [finds all of them](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S6lQ7.png) in the `A2:E{last}` range.

Comment: SGreg, Sorry, I did not set the range Range properly, works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

just add this line in your code:

```
MsgBox "BlankCells are:" & Range("A2:E" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Sub ShowBlanks()
    Dim data As Range, cl As Range, blanks As String

        Set data = Range("A1:E" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        blanks = vbNullString

        For Each cl In data
            If cl.Value = vbNullString Then
                blanks = blanks & cl.Address & vbCrLf & vbLf
            End If
        Next cl

        MsgBox "These cell are empty:" & vbCrLf & vbLf & blanks
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Alex, when I run your Sub I get only the first empty cell it encounters, I made two empty cell to test with is the sub supose to capture all the empty cells or just the first?.  Thanks

Comment: Alex, this works great like the 1st awnser I did not set the range properly. Thank you